# Method overload runs with least specific type with inline if statement

Tags: apex, inline, method-invocation

I had the impression that when we overload, it will run with the most specific type(Date for example). In the following example, it always runs with least specific type (Object):

```
String.valueOf((true)?(Date)sObject.get(fieldName):sObject.get(fieldName));
//this will print 2018-11-22 00:00:00
```

However, if we do not use inline:

```
String oldValue;
if (true){
  oldValue = String.valueOf((Date)sObject.get(fieldName));
} else {
  oldValue = String.valueOf(sObject.get(fieldName));
}

//this will print 2018-11-22
```

Could someone provide more background on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ternary is returning the compile-time type of `Object`. So, this is the expected behaviour of calling methods with overloaded parameters. This resolution is done at compile time.

From the Java spec (I don't know of a similar Apex spec)

> If the compile-time declaration for the method invocation is a
>   signature polymorphic method, then [...] The compile-time parameter types are the types of the actual argument
>   expressions.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3

This may be confusing because calling virtual methods overridden in a subclass is resolved at run-time.

In code, the following is true:

```
@IsTest
private class OverloadingTest {

    enum Result {
        BASE_OBJECT,
        BASE_STRING,
        SUBCLASS_OBJECT,
        SUBCLASS_STRING
    }

    private virtual class Base {
        virtual Result f(Object o) {
            return Result.BASE_OBJECT;
        }
        virtual Result f(String s) {
            return Result.BASE_STRING;
        }
    }

    private class Subclass extends Base {
        private override Result f(Object o) {
            return Result.SUBCLASS_OBJECT;
        }

        private override Result f(String s) {
            return Result.SUBCLASS_STRING;
        }

    }

    @IsTest
    static void testBehaviour() {
        Base base = new Base();
        Base subclassAsBase = new Subclass();
        String s = 's';
        Object sAsObject = (Object)s;

        System.assertEquals(Result.BASE_OBJECT, base.f(sAsObject));
        System.assertEquals(Result.BASE_STRING, base.f(s));

        System.assertEquals(Result.SUBCLASS_OBJECT, subclassAsBase.f(sAsObject));
        System.assertEquals(Result.SUBCLASS_STRING, subclassAsBase.f(s));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! I was expecting this answer since `String.valueOf((true)?(Date)sObject.get(fieldName):(Date)sObject.get(fieldName));`  was calling String.valueOf(Date). However, I got confused when I tested an overriden method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use **String.valueOf()** for *ternary operator*, not for *Date* exactly. The result of ternary operator will be Object, however, if you type something like this:

```
system.debug(true ? String.valueOf((Date) sObject.get(fieldName)) : String.valueOf(sObject.get(fieldName))); //2019-11-26
```

everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks. I was  trying to find the reason of this behaviour, overloading happens on compile time as @Aidan explained.